# Filling in a textbox with values from checkboxes

Tags: javascript, textbox, checkbox

Here is the code I have so far

```
  <head>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  function list(c,n,z) {
   s=document.form.marktext.value;
  if (c.checked) {
  if (s.indexOf(n)<0) s+=', '+n;
  } else {
  s=document.form.marktext.value.replace(', '+n,'');
 }
  z=", ";
  if (s.substring(2) == z) s=s.substring(2);
  document.form.marktext.value=s;}



  function getchecked() {
      var newtxt = '';
      var chkbx = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

      for(var i = 0; i < chkbx.length; i ++) 
        {
          if(chkbx[i].type == 'checkbox' && chkbx[i].checked === true) {
          if(newtxt.length !== 0) {
            newtxt += ',';
            }
            newtxt += chkbx.innerHTML;
        }

  }

  document.form.marktext.value = newtxt;

  }

  </script>

  </head>


  <body>
  <form name="form">
  <input type="text" value="" name="marktext"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="mark" value="word" onclick="getchecked()">Word<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="mark" onclick="getchecked()">Type<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="mark" onclick="getchecked()">Other<br>
  </form>


  </body>
```

It almost works but when I click a checkbox, I am getting an 'undefined' label in the textbox instead of the checkbox value.  I am guessing it is something small and stupid but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the index on `newtxt += chkbx[i].value;` instead of `newtxt += chkbx.innerHTML;`

```
  <head>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  function list(c,n,z) {
   s=document.form.marktext.value;
  if (c.checked) {
  if (s.indexOf(n)<0) s+=', '+n;
  } else {
  s=document.form.marktext.value.replace(', '+n,'');
 }
  z=", ";
  if (s.substring(2) == z) s=s.substring(2);
  document.form.marktext.value=s;}



  function getchecked() {

      var newtxt = '';
      var chkbx = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

        for(var i = 0; i < chkbx.length; i ++) 
    {
      if(chkbx[i].type == 'checkbox' && chkbx[i].checked === true) {
      if(newtxt.length !== 0) {
        newtxt += ',';
        }
        newtxt += chkbx[i].value;
    }

    }

  document.form.marktext.value = newtxt;

  }

  </script>

  </head>


  <body>
  <form name="form">
  <input type="text" value="" name="marktext"><br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="mark" value="word" onclick="getchecked()">Word<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="mark" onclick="getchecked()" value="type">Type<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="mark" onclick="getchecked()" value="other">Other<br>

  </form>


  </body>
```

But my suggestion use jQuery or any other javascript library!!

Comment: @TDO also remember to put the values on checkbox, not innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

The propoerty innerHtml doesn't apply to gather Textboxes labels. Plus, the way you coded it, these are not labels.

Look at this link, i think your solution is inside : http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/finding_the_value_of_a_checkbox.php3

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
newtxt += chkbx.innerHTML;
```

to

```
newtxt += chkbx[i].nextSibling.data;
```

`<input>` does not have an innerHTML but it has a sibling - the text node next to it. And you probably want to display the "content" of this text node. (Note: your output was "undefined" because you called `innerHTML` on the array  and not on a `<input>` node)